# libreoffice convert files with php in separate docker containers

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, libreoffice

I have an existing Laravel app running in the `PHP-fpm-alpine` & `Nginx docker containers` (single docker-compose file). I now need to get a total word count from the uploaded `doc / docx` files, and I think LibreOffice is the way to go.

If I install LibreOffice and all the dependencies in the existing PHP image, I can perform a command to transform `doc / docx` file to `txt` by running the following command, and then parse the txt with PHP to count words:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to txt sourcefile.doc --outdir...
```

The downside to this is that it will bloat the PHP image with unnecessary dependencies and if LibreOffice service breaks, the whole web app is offline. So I want to extract LibreOffice to a different service (something like this https://github.com/lcrea/libreoffice-headless).

But how can I trigger the LibreOffice CLI command from PHP (different container) and then access the converted file?

I heard about using shared volume(folder), `docker` & `sockets`, but that is a significant security risk.

Ps: I tried using PHPWord instead of LibreOffice, but it does not accept `DOC` file format, only `DOCX`.

Answer (score 0):

I came here searching for the same question and I find this solution:
[Versed](https://github.com/sgbj/versed)

This is a good assembled image, which exposes a web API for converting files.

In docker compose file put that converter to the same network where application are and named to 'converter'.
In the controller this is the relevant part using the converter microservice from application:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Http\Client\ConnectionException;

$export_file = public_path('testfile.docx');    //existing file to convert
$pdf_file = public_path('testfile.pdf');
$handler = fopen($export_file, 'r');
try {
    $response = Http::attach('file', $handler)
            ->timeout(3)
            ->withOptions([
                'sink' => $pdf_file
            ])
            ->post(config('custom.converter_endpoint'), [
                'format' => 'pdf',
            ]);
} catch (ConnectionException $e){
    return $export_file;    //if service is not avaiable, return docx file
} finally {
    fclose($handler);
}
if ($response->successful()){
    unlink($export_file);   //Delete original file! Not necessary, I just used in my export controller bc it was temporary file
    return $pdf_file;
} else {
    return $export_file;    //if any error, return docx file
}
```

/config/custom.php :

```
return [
    'converter_endpoint' => env('CONVERTER_ENDPOINT', 'http://converter:3000/convert')
];
```